# Compare two delimited strings and return corresponding value in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two columns with a hashtag delimited value, i.e. `Email#Web#Telephone#SMS#MMS` & `0#0#0#1#0` Note that each delimited value of the second column matches up with its corresponding delimited value in the first column, i.e. `Email = 0`, `Web = 0`, `Telephone = 0`, `SMS = 1` etc.
Based on a parameter, I want to return the matching value of the second column. i.e. incoming param = `Web#Telephone#SMS`, thus the value that I want to return is `0#0#1`.

This need to be done in PL SQL, and I have no clue where to start, which explains the lack of sample code.

Any help please?

Comment: I have looked into using CTEs, but that will result in having a common denominator to join the two CTEs which will probably have nothing to do with eachother. If this was TSQL I'd use a table variable and query the table with the parameter.

Comment: Could you provide create and insert statements for your table, along with the expected output from your code, please? Also, how is your code going to be used? How is it going to be called? On the face of it, it sounds like something that could be done in a single SQL statement - research splitting a delimited string.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of very useful utility functions in an Oracle package called APEX_UTIL.  (This package concerns Oracle Application Express aka APEX, but can be used anywhere).  They are:

- apex_util.string_to_table
- apex_util.table_to_string

Using `string_to_table` you can convert the delimited string into a table of values:

```
declare
   v_table apex_application_global.vc_arr2; -- This is the table type apex_util uses
begin
   v_table := apex_util.table_to_string ('Email#Web#Telephone#SMS#MMS', '#');
end;
```

You now have an array with 5 elements ('Email', 'Web', 'Telephone', 'SMS', 'MMS');

You can do the same with the values string to get a table with elements ('0', '0', '0', '1', 0').  And you can do the same with the parameter to get a table with elements ('Web', 'Telephone', 'SMS').

You can then use PL/SQL logic to build a new array with elements for the values you need to return, i.e. ('0', '0', '1').  I have left this part to you!

Finally you can turn that back into a delimited string:

```
return apex_util.table_to_string (v_return_table, '#');
```

Comment: Okay great! Thanks Tony. Will post my solution when I'm done.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should **normalize** the table and have the attributes in different **columns** rather than **delimited strings** in a single column.

Anyway, you could do it in many ways using the techniques to [Split comma delimited strings in a table](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/category/oracle-delimited-string-manipulation/)

For example, using **REGEXP_SUBSTR** and **CONNECT BY** clause:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(attr, val) AS(
  2  SELECT 'Email#Web#Telephone#SMS#MMS', '0#0#0#1#0' FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT lines.COLUMN_VALUE,
  5    trim(regexp_substr(t.attr, '[^#]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) attr,
  6    trim(regexp_substr(t.val, '[^#]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) val
  7  FROM data t,
  8    TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
  9    (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.attr, '#')+1
 10    ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 11  /

COLUMN_VALUE ATTR                        VAL
------------ --------------------------- ---------
           1 Email                       0
           2 Web                         0
           3 Telephone                   0
           4 SMS                         1
           5 MMS                         0

SQL>
```

Now, you can get the respective values for each attribute.

You could put the entire logic in a **FUNCTION** and return the corresponding values of each attribute and call the function in **SELECT** statement.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION get_val_from_attr(
  3        attr_name VARCHAR2)
  4      RETURN NUMBER
  5    IS
  6      var_val NUMBER;
  7    BEGIN
  8    WITH DATA(attr, val) AS
  9      ( SELECT 'Email#Web#Telephone#SMS#MMS', '0#0#0#1#0' FROM dual
 10      ),
 11      t2 AS
 12      (SELECT lines.COLUMN_VALUE,
 13        trim(regexp_substr(t.attr, '[^#]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) attr,
 14        trim(regexp_substr(t.val, '[^#]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) val
 15      FROM data t,
 16        TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
 17        (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.attr, '#')+1
 18        ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 19      )
 20    SELECT val INTO var_val FROM t2 WHERE attr = attr_name;
 21    RETURN var_val;
 22  END;
 23  /

Function created.
```

Let's call the **function**:

```
SQL> SELECT get_val_from_attr('Email') FROM dual;

GET_VAL_FROM_ATTR('EMAIL')
--------------------------
                         0

SQL> SELECT get_val_from_attr('SMS') FROM dual;

GET_VAL_FROM_ATTR('SMS')
------------------------
                       1
```